# How to get Tagit Tags from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tags, tag-it

Here I am using [tagIt plugin](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html).I have implemented it on `Asp.net TextBox` And now i want to get all tags which is in textbox.But I am not able to get Tags or Tags text from textbox.

I am trying Something as below.

Here my Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=TxtMetaKey.ClientID %>').tagit({
                allowSpaces: true
            });
            $("#<%=btntest.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                getTagsString($('#<%=TxtMetaKey.ClientID %> li').text())
                var tagStr = JSON.stringify($('#<%=TxtMetaKey.ClientID %>').tagit("tagLabel"));
                alert("function is called" + tagStr);
            });
        });

        function getTagsString(tags) {
            var string = "";
            alert(tags);
            for (var i in tags) {
                string += tags[i] + ",";
                alert("Value of string is : "+string);
            }
            alert($("#<%= hdnSelectedTags.ClientID %>").val(string));
        }
</script>
```

Source Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtMetaKey" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btntest" runat="server" Text="Test" ValidationGroup="DialogGroup"
                    class="form-control"></asp:Button>
</div>
```

So if somebody have solution of this problem then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware the plug-in has it's own method to do this? `assignedTags` is meant to return a string array of all tags currently in the widget.

e.g.

```
var tagStrArr = $('#<%=TxtMetaKey.ClientID %>').tagit("assignedTags");
```